# Creating a 10-mile radius buffer zone that averages a variable in my shapefile?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, buffer

I´m trying to create a "buffer zone" for every polygon in my shapefile, which will identify a 10 mile radius around the centroid of each polygon, and calculate the AVERAGE "demand for services" (one variable in my shapefile attribute table) for all the surrounding polygons within this radius. All of the relevant polygons are in the same layer/shapefile.

Ideally, this average would be calculated in a new field in the attribute table, so that I can symbolize this variable and get a more even "heat map" of demand (which is not as tied to the municipality boundaries.)

Can anyone help me out with instructions on how to do this?

Comment: You can use [Feature to Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000) to convert your polygons to points at the centroid, then buffer that.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should do [Feature To Point](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000003m000000) in order to create your centroids.

Then, you obviously need to create your buffer.

For the third step is to use [Tabulate Intersection](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000044000000) to know how much of each polygon is under your buffer.

Finally, you summarize your table to get your synthetic value and you join the resulting table to your original polygons (or to the centroids).